# $scope.apply() working but flashing and reloading DOM for entire controller (and parent controller)

Tags: angularjs, chat

I'm building a chat with the layer web UI and sdk. Everything is working well — the current conversation changes and the correct css classes are applied (e.g., 'selected-conversation'). However, the ChatCtrl and it's parent controller refresh entirely and they flash on the screen (which looks buggy). I need the $scope.apply() to apply the changes but I can't figure out how to call $scope.apply() without it refreshing the controllers.

Would greatly appreciate ANY ideas on how to solve this.

**HTML**

```
<layer-conversations-list 
  ng-client="appCtrlState.client" 
  ng-selected-conversation-id="chatCtrlState.currentConversation.id" 
  ng-conversation-selected="selectConversation">
</layer-conversations-list>
```

**ChatCtrl**

```
$scope.$watch('$locationChangeSuccess', handleLocation);

function handleLocation() {

  var matches = $location.$$url.match(/\/conversations\/.{8}-.{4}-.{4}-.{4}-.{12}$/);
  // If the url matches a Conversation URL, show it.
  if (matches) {
    if ($scope.appCtrlState.client.isReady) {
      $scope.loadConversation('layer://' + matches[0]);
    } else {
      $scope.appCtrlState.client.once('ready', function() {
        $scope.loadConversation('layer://' + matches[0]);
      });
    }
    $scope.chatCtrlState.showParticipants = false;
  }
}

 /**
 * The user selects a Conversation in the <layer-conversations-list>
 */
function selectConversation(evt) {
  $scope.updateSelectedConversation(evt.detail.conversation);
  $scope.$apply();
};

function updateSelectedConversation(conversation) {
  $scope.chatCtrlState.currentConversation = conversation.toObject();
  $location.path(conversation.id.substring(8));
};
```

Comment: have you try to see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak ?

Comment: @LorenzoBerti, yes. The controller loads fine. The flash occurs when I click on a conversation in the conversationList, I update the currentConversation, and then call $scope.$apply()

Comment: Instead of handling the path change with `$locationChangeSuccess`, use `$locationChangeStart` to abort the default action and process the location there.

Comment: mmh, I do not know if I understand correctly, but in general $scope.apply() not refresh ctrl, it force new digest cycle. If you try to change location and you don't want refresh/reload ctrl you can use: reloadOnSearch: false on $routeprovider.when(), but if the problem is only "graphics", when you reload data you can use a loading or placeholder with ngIf